# Hudson:java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cvs" : CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I am using hudson 2.2.0 for a test application.At the basic level I want to take check out form my cvs.
For this I have created a new job and configured.But while build this job it is giving me error.
Below is the error console:

`Started by user anonymous
[formcsam] $ cvs -Q -z3 -d :pserver:username:password@host:/root co -P -d workspace -D "Friday, May 18, 2012 5:51:37 AM UTC" core/myapp
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cvs" (in directory "C:\Documents and Settings\sanjay\.hudson\jobs\formcsam"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:192)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:164)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:639)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:274)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:281)
    at hudson.scm.CVSSCM.run(CVSSCM.java:575)
    at hudson.scm.CVSSCM.run(CVSSCM.java:585)
    at hudson.scm.CVSSCM.checkout(CVSSCM.java:756)
    at hudson.scm.CVSSCM.checkout(CVSSCM.java:319)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1479)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:507)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:424)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1366)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: formcsam #1 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE`

Then I copied the same command to fire it from command prompt.From command prompt it is working fine.So I am not getting what is the issues in hudson while firing the same command    .

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just forgot to add cvs.exe in configuration of hudson.